# Check if textbox has a value

Tags: php

I am using a form to insert data to my database. I have a textbox with the ID and NAME `name1`.

If the user clicks on submit the PHP script sends the data to my database. But the insert statement is also executed when the textbox is empty. If there is no data entered the script creates an empty row in the database.

In my PHP script I want to check if the (value) in the textbox is empty or not.

I have tried multiple codes but the script still sends the empty data to my database.

Does someone know how I can check if there is data entered in the textbox.

Here is my script:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO product(user_id, name, price, tax) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query1);
$exec1 = $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['USER_ID'], $name1, $price1, $tax1));

if($exec1){

echo '<p>product1 is created</p>';  

} else {
echo '<p>error</p>';
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you are not checking if the text field is empty. Please try this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name1'])) {
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO product(user_id, name, price, tax) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query1);
    $exec1 = $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['USER_ID'], $name1, $price1, $tax1));

    if($exec1){

    echo '<p>product1 is created</p>';  

    } else {
    echo '<p>error</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this script inserting data if name1 is empty?. I want to execute the command if `name1` it is not empty

Comment: No sorry, I will try :)

Answer (score 0):

check if a field is empty in order to return an error or a message just do this (brief example):

```
if (!(empty($_POST['textbox']))){
    execute some code....
}
else {
     execute some code... 
}
```

Comment: *"First of all use mysql_real_escape_string() to avoid MYSQL injections."* - No and even that old function can still be bypassed. On top of that, the OP is already using the `mysqli_` api *with* a prepared statement.